# On-the-fly upgrading a COM object used in a .NET application

Tags: .net, com, interop, activex

We have a large, deployed, 3-tier .NET application which for good business reasons can't be upgraded at present.  The client makes use of a number of classic c++ ActiveX controls through the usual interop mechanism.

We have fixed some critical bugs in one of the ActiveX controls and need to deploy the fixes to a number of customers without reinstalling the client.  Patches are allowed, including upgrading dlls.  Is there a way to install a bug-fixed ActiveX dll without requiring a new client?  The interface, filename, GUIDs, etc., are all unchanged.

I've tried just replacing the dll without success -- got a variety of somewhat strange errors, but it's possible that the ActiveX dll (which is still in development) is defective -- that's being followed up in parallel.

Should simply substituting the dlls work?  If not, can you suggest another approach short of rebuilding then reinstalling the client which ought to work?

Comment: While the errors you see might look like Chinese to you, they can provide an important diagnostic to others.  That's what they were meant to do.  Anything is better than "doesn't work".

Comment: A fair point -- they're not in the bug reports, but I should be able to get them.

Answer (score 0):

If the interface hasn't changed then overwriting the original dll will work.

Comment: FWIW, I was unable to make this work this way.  Extensive work with Microsoft MSDN Support finally got it working by also replacing the two generated interops.  I still don't understand why.  And I'd be interested in finding a reference explsaining exactly how the C++->interop->COM interface works.

Answer (score 0):

how about unregistering before replacing it, and then re-registering.

```
regsvr32.exe /u [YOUR DLL HERE]
```

then overwrite the dll, then

```
regsvr32.exe [YOUR DLL HERE]
```

Comment: As far as I can see this should have no effect whatsoever if the interfaces, names & GUIDs are identical.  True?

Comment: Yeah, I also think that's right, but it will do no harm and I could swear I've hit cases where it seemed like it should be unnecessary but did the trick.